# select.prev(".class").val(); returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to return the value linked to a class within the html page. It doesn't return the value stated, it returns undefined. I added a console.log to show what I am outputting and it states undefined.

```js
$(document).on("change", "select.playlist", function() {
  var select = $(this);
  var songId = select.prev(".songId").val();
  var playlistId = select.val();
  //selects dropdown menu thats currently selected
  console.log("playlistId: " + playlistId);
  console.log("songId: " + songId);
});

function showOptions(button) {
  var songId = $(button).prevAll(".songId").val();
  var menu = $(".optionsMenu");

  var menuWidth = menu.width();
  menu.find(".songId").val(songId);

  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset = $(button).offset().top;

  var top = elementOffset - scrollTop;

  var right = $(button).position().right;

  menu.css({
    "top": top + 8 + "px",
    "right": +menuWidth - 100 + "px",
    "display": "inline"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='songOptions'>
  <input type='hidden' class='songId' value='" . $albumTrack->getId() . "'>
  <img class='optionsButton' onclick='showOptions(this)' src='assets/images/icons/more.png'>
</div>
```

The console.log() should output the value matching the one you see when you inspect elements.

Comment: where are you including your js file in the html document? you should consider putting your logic inside $(document).ready() that way all your html is loaded before your js. I'm guessing your js is being loaded first and thats why you have undefined

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are having is actually because when you call `this` in the onclick like you are, you are getting the `HTML` of the tag and not the object itself. I removed the onclick and change it to a click event listener and it works.

```js
$(document).on("change", "select.playlist", function() {
  var select = $(this);
  var songId = select.prev(".songId").val();
  var playlistId = select.val();
  //selects dropdown menu thats currently selected
  console.log("playlistId: " + playlistId);
  console.log("songId: " + songId);
});



$(document).on("click",".optionsButton",function(){
  var songId = $(this).prevAll(".songId").val();
  console.log(songId);
  var menu = $(".optionsMenu");

  var menuWidth = menu.width();
  menu.find(".songId").val(songId);

  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

  var elementOffset = $(this).offset().top;

  var top = elementOffset - scrollTop;

  var right = $(this).position().right;

  menu.css({
    "top": top + 8 + "px",
    "right": +menuWidth - 100 + "px",
    "display": "inline"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='songOptions'>
  <input type='hidden' class='songId' value='" . $albumTrack->getId() . "'>
  <img class='optionsButton' src='assets/images/icons/more.png'>
</div>
```